# Am I able to change the ControlID of an asp:ControlParameter in an asp:DataSource in code behind?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

As the title states I am trying to change the `controlID` for a control parameter in an `asp:datasource` via code-behind.

Currently I have this `<asp:SqlDataSource>`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceRepairPart" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WarrantyConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT a.RecID, a.[Description] 
                    FROM RepairPartTypes AS a
                    INNER JOIN EquipmentParts AS b ON a.RecID = b.RepairPartID
                    INNER JOIN EquipmentType AS c ON b.EquipmentID = c.RecID
                    INNER JOIN Equipment AS d ON c.EquipmentType = d.EquipmentType
                    WHERE a.TypeCode IN ('L','PL')
                      AND (d.Agreement = @AgreementNumber)
                      AND (c.EquipmentType = @EquipmentType)
                    ORDER BY a.[Description] ">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblAgreement" Name="AgreementNumber" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I just recently added the parameter `@EquipmentType`. Normally I would add the parameter in the `SelectParameters` section in a similar fashion as the `AgreementNumber` parameter, however the key difference between the two is that `AgreementNumber` is always tied to the `lblAgreement` label control, whereas the `@EquipmentType` parameter will be tied to different controls depending on specific criteria.

Essentially, this `SqlDataSource` populates a number of drop down lists based on a selection in a different drop down list, all housed within a gridview. I will post the markup for the gridview below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
     EmptyDataText="No Claimed Labor" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
     ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" DataKeyNames="RecID"
     ShowFooter="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" Width="95%"
     OnRowDataBound="GV1OnRowDataBound" >
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />

    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRepairEquipmentNew" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePartEquipment" DataValueField="RecID"
            DataTextField="EquipmentPart" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" Width="220px" Height="20px"
            Style="margin-left: 70px;" > <%-- Removed the OnSelectedIndexChanged (add if needed) --%>
            <asp:ListItem Value ="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRepairNew" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceRepairPart" DataValueField="RecID"
            DataTextField="Description" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="220px"  Height="20px" AutoPostBack="true"
            style="" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRepairNew_SelectedIndexChanged"
            OnDataBinding="ddlRepairNew_DataBinding">
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
<%--        <asp:textbox ID="txtDescOther" runat="server" Width="235px" Visible="false" />--%>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtRepairHoursNew" Width="95px" Style="margin-left: 68px" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtHoursRequestedNew_TextChanged" OnKeyPress="GVTextBox_KeyPress" />
        <%--<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblRepairHoursAllowed"></asp:Label>--%>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidAllowedRepairHoursNew" />
<%--        <asp:textbox ID="txtAllowedHoursNew" runat="server" Width="90px"/>--%>
        <asp:textbox ID="txtRepairCostNew" runat="server" Width="95px" ReadOnly="False" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtRepairCostNew_TextChanged"/>
        <asp:textbox ID="txtLineTotalNew" runat="server" Width="95px" ReadOnly="true"/>
        <asp:textbox ID="txtTaxNew" runat="server" Width="95px" text="0"/>
        <asp:Button ID="InsertDetail" runat="server" CommandName="InsertDetail" Height="25px" Text="Add Detail" Width="85px" />
    </EmptyDataTemplate>

    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" FooterText="Add -->" ShowDeleteButton="True" HeaderStyle-Width="70px" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RecID" HeaderText="RecID" SortExpression="RecID" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Equipment / Repair / Labor Description" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRepairEquipmentType" Text='<%# Bind("EquipmentType") %>' runat="server" Enabled="False" Width="220px" />
                    <asp:label ID="lblRepairType" Text='<%# Bind("RepairType") %>' runat="server" Enabled="False" Width="220px"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRepairEquipmentEdit" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePartEquipment" DataValueField="RecID" DataTextField="EquipmentPart" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("EquipmentID") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" Width="220px" Height="20px" >
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRepairEdit" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceRepairPart" DataValueField="RecID" DataTextField="Description" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("RepairID")%>' AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="true" Width="220px" Height="20px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRepairEdit_SelectedIndexChanged" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRepairEquipmentInsert" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePartEquipment" DataValueField="RecID" DataTextField="EquipmentPart" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" Width="220px" Height="20px" Style="margin-left: 29px" >
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRepairInsert" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceRepairPart" DataValueField="RecID" DataTextField="Description" AppendDataBoundItems="True" autopostback="true" Width="220px" Height="20px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRepairInsert_SelectedIndexChanged" OnDataBinding="ddlRepairInsert_DataBinding">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">---SELECT---</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Repair Hours Requested" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:label ID="lblRepairHours" Text='<%# Bind("RepairHours")%>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRepairHoursEdit" Text='<%# Bind("RepairHours")%>' runat="server" Width="95px" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtHoursRequestedEdit_TextChanged" />
                        <%--<asp:Label ID="lblRepairHoursEdit" runat="server"></asp:Label>--%>
                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidAllowedRepairHoursEdit" Value='<%# Bind("AllowedHours")%>' />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRepairHoursInsert" runat="server" Style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtHoursRequestedInsert_TextChanged" />
                <%--<center><asp:Label ID="lblRepairHoursInsert" runat="server"></asp:Label></center>--%>
                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidAllowedRepairHoursInsert" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <%--<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Repair Hours Approved" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:label ID="lblAllowedHours" Text='<%# Bind("AllowedHours")%>' runat="server" Width="50px"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:textbox ID="txtAllowedHoursEdit" Text='<%# Bind("AllowedHours")%>' Enabled="true" runat="server" Width="50px"/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:textbox ID="txtAllowedHoursInsert" Text='<%# Bind("AllowedHours")%>' runat="server" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>--%>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Labor Rate" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:label ID="lblRepairCost" Text='<%# Bind("RepairCost", "{0:C}") %>' runat="server" Enabled="False"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="txtRepairCostEdit" Text='<%# Bind("RepairCost") %>' runat="server" ReadOnly="False" Width="95px" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtRepairCostEdit_TextChanged"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="txtRepairCostInsert" Text='<%# Bind("RepairCost") %>' runat="server" ReadOnly="False" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtRepairCostInsert_TextChanged"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Repair Total" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:label ID="lblRepairTotal" Text='<%# Bind("LaborRequested", "{0:C}")%>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="txtRepairTotalEdit" Text='<%# Bind("LaborRequested")%>' ReadOnly="True" runat="server" Width="95px"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="txtRepairTotalInsert" Text='<%# Bind("LaborRequested") %>' runat="server" ReadOnly="True" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tax" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbTaxTotal" Text='<%# Bind("Tax", "{0:C}")%>' runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidRepairGST" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("GST")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidRepairPST" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("PST")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidRepairQST" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("QST")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidRepairHST" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("HST")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="lblTaxTotalEdit" Text='<%# Bind("Tax")%>' Enabled="true" runat="server" Width="95px"/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="txtTaxTotalInsert" runat="server" Enabled="true" text="0" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Insert New" HeaderStyle-Width="85px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblEmpty" Text="" runat="server" Width="85px"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Insert" runat="server" CommandName="InsertNewDetail" Height="22px" Text="Insert" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;" />
        </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336699" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Bare with me, I understand this is probably incredibly inefficient, but I haven't had the time to redesign the page this is on. The controls in question are `ddlRepairEquipmentNew` (Edit/Insert) and `ddlRepairNew` (Edit/Insert).

The selection made in the `ddlRepairEquipmentNew` dropdowns will modify the items that display in `ddlRepairNew` using the query above.

I need the `@EquipmentType` parameter value to be equal to whatever is selected in `ddlRepairEquipmentNew`.

Here's where the problem arises, I cannot just add:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlRepairEquipmentNew" Name="AgreementNumber" />
```

because the control ID will change throughout the process.

Essentially what happens is that when a user first comes to this page they are presented with an empty gridview with the "New" controls in an `EmptyDataTemplate` and when they insert the first record the controls in question switch to the "Insert" controls.

If an existing record in the gridview is edited then the "Edit" control appears. I created conditionals to determine which controls are currently active on the gridview and I attempt to assign that controls value to the data source parameter.

The conditional code that I am using is as follows:

```
 Dim gv As GridView = sender
    For Each row As GridViewRow In gv.Rows
        If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim ddlRepairEquipmentEdit As DropDownList = TryCast(row.FindControl("ddlRepairEquipmentEdit"), DropDownList)
            Dim ddlRepairEquipmentInsert As DropDownList = TryCast(gv.FooterRow?.FindControl("ddlRepairEquipmentInsert"), DropDownList)
            Dim ddlRepairEquipmentNew As DropDownList = TryCast(gv.Controls(0).Controls(0).FindControl("ddlRepairEquipmentNew"), DropDownList)

            'Dim equipmentType As ControlParameter = SqlDataSourceRepairPart.SelectParameters("@EquipmentType")

            If gv.EditIndex = row.RowIndex AndAlso ddlRepairEquipmentEdit IsNot Nothing Then
                SqlDataSourceRepairPart.SelectParameters.Remove(SqlDataSourceRepairPart.SelectParameters("@EquipmentType"))
                SqlDataSourceRepairPart.SelectParameters.Add("EquipmentType", ddlRepairEquipmentEdit.SelectedValue)
            ElseIf gv.EditIndex = -1 AndAlso gv.Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso ddlRepairEquipmentInsert IsNot Nothing Then
                SqlDataSourceRepairPart.SelectParameters.Remove(SqlDataSourceRepairPart.SelectParameters("@EquipmentType"))
                SqlDataSourceRepairPart.SelectParameters.Add("EquipmentType", ddlRepairEquipmentInsert.SelectedValue)
            ElseIf gv.EditIndex = -1 AndAlso gv.Rows.Count = 0 AndAlso ddlRepairEquipmentNew IsNot Nothing Then
                SqlDataSourceRepairPart.SelectParameters.Remove(SqlDataSourceRepairPart.SelectParameters("@EquipmentType"))
                SqlDataSourceRepairPart.SelectParameters.Add("EquipmentType", ddlRepairEquipmentNew.SelectedValue)
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

I understand if the conditions above will not work as intended but I cannot seem to get past the assignment of the scalar variable `@EquipmentType` in order to determine if these conditions will work as intended.

What I've tried so far is to associate the value of the appropriate control to the `SelectParameter` in the `GridView1_DataBound()` event, the `GridView1_DataBinding()` event, the `GridView1_OnRowDataBound()` event as well as the `Page_Load()` event before the `GridView1.DataBind()` method is called in the first place.

When doing this, the `GridView1_DataBound` event throws an error

> Must declare scalar variable "@EquipmentType"

The `GridView1_OnRowDataBound()` event throws a null reference exception saying the controls I'm referencing do not exist, leading me to believe that its trying to assign the parameter before the controls are instantiated.

The `GridView1_DataBinding()` event throws the same "Must declare scalar variable" error.

And the `page_load()` event throws the "Must Declare" error as well.

I intended to try to set the value of the parameter in the `selectedIndexChanged` event for the `ddlRepairEquipmentNew` controls, so that the selected index of the aforementioned ddl isn't 0, but I am concerned that will trigger an error on page load because there won't be anything selected in the control yet, thus maybe triggering a null reference?

I would be truly grateful to anyone who might have some insight on how to do something like this. As I stated above I am well aware that this definitely may not be the most effective way to do what I am trying to do especially with having all of my controls in a gridview in this manner, but unfortunately this is what I am presented with and before I can redesign this form I need to find a solution to this problem so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I have tried adding the `Select` parameter in the databound and databinding event for the `ddlRepairNew` drop downs and I receive the same error

> Must declare scalar variable "@EquipmentType"

when the `Gridview1.DataBind()` method is called in `Page_Load()`